# How to count number of occurrences of a certain char in string?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010

How can I count the number of occurrences of a certain character in a string in Delphi?

For instance, assume that I have the following string and would like to count the number of commas in it:

```
S := '1,2,3';
```

Then I would like to obtain `2` as the result.

Comment: http://delphi.cjcsoft.net//viewthread.php?tid=43892

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use this simple function:

```
function OccurrencesOfChar(const S: string; const C: char): integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    if S[i] = C then
      inc(result);
end;
```

Comment: Can't I do it in a single line?

Comment: @NareshKumar: Yes, of course: `OccurrencesOfChar(myString, ',')`

Comment: +1 but chr is a poor name since it already has meaning. I suggest C

Answer (score 20):

Even though an answer has already been accepted, I'm posting the more general function below because I find it so elegant. This solution is for counting the occurrences of a string rather than a character.

```
{ Returns a count of the number of occurences of SubText in Text }
function CountOccurences( const SubText: string;
                          const Text: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := Pos(SubText, Text); 
  if Result > 0 then
    Result := (Length(Text) - Length(StringReplace(Text, SubText, '', [rfReplaceAll]))) div  Length(subtext);
end;  { CountOccurences }
```

Comment: Interesting point of view! Maybe you could simplify the first statement to `Result := Pos(SubText, Text); if Result > 0 then...` [+1]

Comment: This is sick and beautiful :) Obviously it's not very efficient but the trick itself behind the code is something programming should be about!

Comment: Cute, but I'd hate finding this in code.  If you're reading someone's code and run into this, you have to stop and think about how it works, then check to see if it's right.  Code Should Be Clear.  Sorry, but I don't find this elegant.  To me, elegant means concise and obviously correct with a small + for clever.

Comment: It is also significantly slower than a simple loop over the characters.

Answer (score 18):

And for those who prefer the  enumerator loop in modern Delphi versions (not any better than the accepted solution by Andreas, just an alternative solution):

```
function OccurrencesOfChar(const ContentString: string;
  const CharToCount: char): integer;
var
  C: Char;
begin
  result := 0;
  for C in ContentString do
    if C = CharToCount then
      Inc(result);
end;
```

Answer (score 12):

This one can do the work for if you're not handling large text

...

```
uses RegularExpressions;
```

...

```
function CountChar(const s: string; const c: char): integer;
begin
 Result:= TRegEx.Matches(s, c).Count
end;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be good on Delphi? Regular expressions are quite good at handling large text bodies.

Comment: It is rather an overkill... Probably many times slower than accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the benefit of StringReplace function as:

```
function OccurencesOfChar(ContentString:string; CharToCount:char):integer;
begin
   Result:= Length(ContentString)-Length(StringReplace(ContentString, CharToCount,'', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]));
end;
```

Comment: Significantly slower than a simple loop over the characters, and (IMHO) slightly less easy to immediate see the correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution and good performance (I wrote for Delphi 7, but should work for other versions as well):

```
function CountOccurences(const ASubString: string; const AString: string): Integer;
var
  iOffset: Integer;
  iSubStrLen: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;

  if (ASubString = '') or (AString = '') then
    Exit;

  iOffset := 1;
  iSubStrLen := Length(ASubString);
  while (True) do
  begin
    iOffset := PosEx(ASubString, AString, iOffset);
    if (iOffset = 0) then
      Break;
    Inc(Result);
    Inc(iOffset, iSubStrLen);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That Copy will make the loop slower. You can do without it if you use [System.Pos](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos) or [AnsiStrings.PosEx](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AnsiStrings.PosEx) with the offset option.

Comment: Correct remark, thanks. Unfortunately in Delphi 7 the Pos function does not have an Offset parameter.

Comment: If you look in StrUtils, you will find the PosEx function in Delphi 7.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... Am I missing something? Why not just...

```
      kSepChar:=',';//to count commas
      bLen:=length(sLineToCheck);
      bCount:=0;//The numer of kSepChars seen so far.
      bPosn:=1;//First character in string is at position 1
      for bPosn:=1 to bLen do begin
         if sLineToCheck[bPosn]=kSepChar then inc(bCount);
         end;//
```

Comment: This is more or less identical to the accepted answer.

Comment: LU RD... Ummm...You're quite right, of course it is. Sorry I missed its previous appearance here. (I've used forums for years, do have SOME idea. Apologies for missing that.)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a recursive solution like that:

```
function CountOccurences(const SubText, Text: string): Integer;
var
  PosRes: Integer;
begin
  // Find the position of SubText in Text
  PosRes := Pos(SubText, Text);

  // If SubText is not found, return 0
  if PosRes = 0 then
    Result := 0
  else
    // If SubText is found, add 1 and call CountOccurences recursively 
    // for the remaining string after the found occurrence
    Result := 1 + CountOccurences(SubText, Copy(Text, PosRes + Length(SubText), MaxInt));
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use built in method ?
I prefer that if it exists.
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.CountChar

Comment: Why don't you give an example of how to use this method?